# SQLite class object unable to instantiate, android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have made a class for SQLITE as below:

```
    public class DatbaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "store";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_DEALER = "dealer";
// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_DEALER_ID = "dealer_id";
private static final String KEY_DEALER_NAME = "dealer_name";

public DatbaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEALER + "("
            + KEY_DEALER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DEALER_NAME
            + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEALER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addContact(Dealer d) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DEALER_ID, d.getDealer_id());
    values.put(KEY_DEALER_NAME, d.getDealer_name());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_DEALER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

I have a dealer class with getter and setter methods as below

```
    public class Dealer {
int dealer_id;
String dealer_name;
public Dealer()
{

}
public Dealer(int id,String name)
{
    this.dealer_id=id;
    this.dealer_name=name;
}
/**
 * @return the dealer_id
 */
public int getDealer_id() {
    return dealer_id;
}
/**
 * @param dealer_id the dealer_id to set
 */
public void setDealer_id(int dealer_id) {
    this.dealer_id = dealer_id;
}
/**
 * @return the dealer_name
 */
public String getDealer_name() {
    return dealer_name;
}
/**
 * @param dealer_name the dealer_name to set
 */
public void setDealer_name(String dealer_name) {
    this.dealer_name = dealer_name;
}
 }
```

So I am parsing an XML and want to save the data in the table. I have created a new class for XML parsing using the pull parser.

When I declare my SQLITE class object as

```
    DatbaseHandler db = new DatbaseHandler(this);
```

I get this error

```
    The constructor DatbaseHandler(SyncXmlParser) is undefined
    //SyncXmlParser is the XML parsing class
```

SyncXMLParser class

```
    public class SyncXmlParser {
private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
private XmlPullParser myparser;
String dataListName, distId, distName, townId, townName, beatName, beatId,
        dealName, dealId;
DatbaseHandler db = new DatbaseHandler(this);
public SyncXmlParser() {
}

public void createXML(String apiResponse) {
    try {
        xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xmlFactoryObject.setNamespaceAware(true);
        myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
        myparser.setInput(new StringReader(apiResponse.substring(
                apiResponse.lastIndexOf("<?xml"),
                apiResponse.indexOf("/DataList") + 10)));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
}

public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (event == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            } else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            } else if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (myParser.getName().equals("DataList")) {

                } else if (myParser.getName().equals("Distributor")) {
                } else if (myParser.getName().equals("Town")) {
                } else if (myParser.getName().equals("Beat")) {
                } else if (myParser.getName().equals("Dealer")) {
                }
            } else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

            } else if (event == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            }
            event = myParser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what is `SyncXmlParser` here?? what kind of object is it?? Is it a context reference, I am guessing it is not

Comment: post the code where you used this DatbaseHandler db = new DatbaseHandler(this);

Comment: @AkhilJain it is not context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you SyncXmlParser class is a java class not android activity class then it give error because DatbaseHandler class need context but  you call class without context.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new SyncXmlParser(SampleActivity.this);
     }
}

public class SyncXmlParser()
{
       private Context context;
        SyncXmlParser(Context context)
          {
this.context=context;
           }

DatbaseHandler db = new DatbaseHandler(context);
}
```

Comment: If you call SyncXmlParser class from activity  then pass activity context fom your activity class to SyncXmlParser construct then pass this context to  DatbaseHandler class.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor takes a Context as its argument. SyncXmlParser is not a Context (and I don't recommend you make it one by extending Context). You need to give some kind of Context, like an Activity or the Application context.

How exactly you choose to do that sort of depends on the structure of your app, but one suggestion might be to use a Dependency Injection framework like Dagger.

Comment: U totally lost me here "use a Dependency Injection framework like Dagger"